# issue while reading xml file

Tags: php, xml, encoding, format, fitnesse

I have to read an XML file that resides on Fitnesse Page.

Let's take an example.

```
<?php
$url = http://localhost:9090/TestSuite.Fitnesse?Suite&Format=XML;
$xml=file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

My XML is in form of:

```
<xml version="some version">
<Results>
<name>Karan</name>
</Results>
...etc...
```

When I output the `$xml` on page, some strange numbers appears to come before each and every tag and output seems to be like

```
37 9 Karan 9f .........and so on....
```

When I checked the source of that webpage, the page containes the below code:

```
37 9
<?XML  Version="some version">
32
<Results>
32
<name>
45
Karan 
0f
</name>
and so on....
```

(I didn't use the exact value, I can provide if needed).

Can anybody help me on this as I was not expecting these strange characters in output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have allow_fopen_url set in your server (php.ini) for this to work.

If you don´t, then you can use this function as a replacement:

```
<?php
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
    {
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        $contents = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);

        if ($contents) return $contents;
            else return FALSE;
    }
?>
```

this will require curl extension enabled in your php.ini

Comment: If ur problem is solved you can choose answer as accepted . thanx and regards

Comment: @chaitanya....I guess i was not clear in explaining my problemm...i have added some more desccription under heading version 2 in the Parent Post ...Please have a look

Comment: please check the Detailed description on the link below for the issue http://pastebin.com/CpLbm4cs

Comment: I narrow downed the issue ...The thing is that when i use `http://localhost:9090/files/testResults/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuite/20120612162442_3_0_0_0.xml` file_get_contents are read fine. but when i use `http://localhost:9090/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuite?suite&format=XML` strange chracters are displayed in output. Is the & and ? chracters in URL causing that issue.

Comment: Thanks a Lot chaitanya !!! That was done and now the XML is read properly without any special Chracters in it. you saved the Day.